# C++ Check file exists without opening it?

Tags: c++, performance

Is there a way to check if a file exists (for now just on Windows) without incurring cost of opening it?

At the moment I am using:

```
ifstream ifile(FilePath);

if(ifile){
```

but the problem is I then put the file into boost mapped_region, thereby opening the file twice. It would be better if I could perform a check for the files existence without having to open it.

Comment: Not in standard C++, because standard C++ has no notion of a file system. However, most *platforms* will provide directory reading facilities.

Comment: You can also use C functions (maybe fopen or stat?)

Comment: There's boost::filesystem::exists if you don't mind using it - I don't know whether it opens it or not, but it probably does the best thing possible.

Comment: AFAIK, The Windows API doesn't support such checks without opening the file. There might always be a call to a CreateFile function with appropriate parameters, which basically confirms accessibility for these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that even if you do check and then try to open, there's always a possibility that the file could be moved / deleted between you checking it and trying the open which is always a hazard with these kinds of operations.

It may be more efficient simply to open the file buffer as part of the creation of the mapped region but be prepared to catch the `interprocess_exception` being thrown on error.

Answer (score 1):

You know, if you attach procmon (from Sysinternals) to your program and look at what Windows is doing under hood, a call to `CreateFile` or `GetFileAttributes` it's going to cause the same amount of overhead, there's no discernible difference in terms of performance.

There are things you can do with the NTFS Journal to speed certain things up but that will only be helpful to specific workloads, not generally for checking the availability of a file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

[access (stduni.h)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html)

What you want to check for is *access(FilePath, F_OK)==0*

This should be a pretty universal way to check if the file exists. As Component 10 said you can't be certain that file exist from the check each time as much can happen in a parallel scenario, but TBH it doesn't matter that much. If an error occur you might want to use the systems GetLastError (MSDN) function or even leave it to the compiler/system to handle to fault, if you handle it yourself, you can ask for name and retry.